# Last action on Row was not recorded because the control does not have any good identification property

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I try to run an UITest on Visual Studio Ultimate 2012. I try to populate a dataGrid in WPF but for some reason I receive  an error when I try to record one test
[error in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR3Q7.png)

It is possible to modify the XAML so I can perform the test correctly? I do not prefer a solution inside C# classes.It's mandatory to solve this in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by binding the `AutomationProperties` in XAML to an existing property that can identify a specific row/item.

Quote from the blog in case it goes down or the post is removed:

> The other alternative is to bind the AutomationProperties.Name property of list item properly.
>
> For example, adding the following code in bold corrects the problem for this List -
>
> ```
> <ListBox Name="GoodList" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Oscar2010}, XPath=BestPictureNomination}">    
>      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
>          <Style>
>              <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding XPath=.}"/>
>          </Style>
>      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
>  </ListBox>
> ```

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gautamg/2010/03/10/how-to-get-automation-working-properly-on-data-bound-wpf-list-or-combo-box/